# error while de-serializing string with escape characters in it

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, deserialization

I hope it is something very simple and must be a common scenario for other devs.

I'm sending an OUT variable from SQL which contains the error details. In my DataLayer API, I check it in VS Debugger and that's how it appears:

```
var string_from_stored_proc = "[{\"errornumber\":2627,\"errormessage\":\"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'KEY_Subject'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'edu.Subject'. The duplicate key value is (MATS10, 2).\",\"errorstate\":1,\"errorseverity\":14,\"errorline\":36,\"errroprocedure\":\"SPCreateSubject\",\"xactstate\":1}]"
```

*I understand that VS debugger adds the escape () to the string.* When I try to deserialize this string using:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<my_error_object>(string_from_stored_proc);
```

I get this error:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'BaaS.DTO.SQLErrorHandler' because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."}

json2csharp.com fails to convert this JSON. If I remove all backslashes, it does the job. Below is the **my_error_object** (or converted by json2sharp) Class:

```
public class my_error_object
{
    public int errornumber { get; set; }
    public string errormessage { get; set; }
    public int errorstate { get; set; }
    public int errorseverity { get; set; }
    public int errorline { get; set; }
    public string errroprocedure { get; set; }
    public int xactstate { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to process the **string_from_stored_proc** and remove all backslashes  but I can't remove the escape chars (which I think is the expected behavior). With those slashes, I'm unable to get the string deserialized.

**Workaround:**
If I use `var outputJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(string_from_stored_proc);` , it gives an output the below output:

```
{[
  {
    "errornumber": 2627,
    "errormessage": "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'KEY_Subject'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'edu.Subject'. The duplicate key value is (MATS10, 2).",
    "errorstate": 1,
    "errorseverity": 14,
    "errorline": 36,
    "errroprocedure": "SPCreateSubject",
    "xactstate": 1
  }
]}
```

Upon removing starting and trailing braces, am able to deserialize using NewtonSoft.

However, when I send it from the DataLayer using `BadRequest(deserialized_string_from_stored_proc)`
and retrieve it in the BusinessLayer using

```
var output = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SQLErrorHandler>();
```

The output variable again has a lot of extra chars which I then need to process again. The only way which works for me is to send the deserialized object using HttpResults.OK(object) and the read it in my BusinessLayer. Which I don't want to do since it is not the correct return type in case of error.

Am I doing it right? I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to deserialize the given string and send over using
   to the BusinessLayer without string processing it?
2. If first is not possible, could I simply pass the string to the
   BusinessLayer and deserialize it there (preferred way)?

I'm happy to provide more info or code snippet to reproduce the error.

**EDIT:**
per @Equalsk's suggestion, I have been able to deserialize it properly. however, it's in the Datalayer at the moment. Here is the output:

```
var equalskObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SQLErrorHandler>>(outputFromSP.Value.ToString());
return Ok(equalskObj);
```

However, I'm still not able to do the preferred way (#2). If I send the string to the BusinessLayer using `return BadRequest(string_from_stored_proc)` it sends

> "{\r\n  \"message\":
>   \"[{\\"errornumber\\":2627,\\"errormessage\\":\\"Violation of
>   UNIQUE KEY constraint 'KEY_Subject'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'edu.Subject'. The duplicate key value is (MATS10,
>   2).\\",\\"errorstate\\":1,\\"errorseverity\\":14,\\"errorline\\":36,\\"errroprocedure\\":\\"SPCreateSubject\\",\\"xactstate\\":1}]\"\r\n}"

Where I still have to process it. Is there a cleaner way of sending it over and then to convert as suggested? I think I should post a simplified question for this since these are separate issues. I'm really interested to see what's the best approach to do it.

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<my_error_object>>(string_from_stored_proc);`?

Comment: It's looking for a list/array type because your SQL string has `[` and `]` around its contents. Remove those, then deserialize.

Comment: @Equalsk - Thanks a bunch. It did the trick. I somehow ignored that it was returning a list even when the return variable set in the Stored Procedure is a varchar (string in C# model).

Comment: However, I'm still stuck with return Ok(object) instead of being able to send a clean error string using BadRequest(string_from_stored_proc) and deserialize it in the BusinessLayer. I have updated the question with the output. Thanks again. @MikeMcCaughan - Though your answer works, it is not something I want to do in first place since it involves manual string processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck with a similar thing. To get the output from your DL, you can return as below:

FROM DL (Called/Second) API

```
return Content(<HttpStatusCode>, "Custom Error Message Here");
```

For example:

```
Return Content(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message.ToString());
```

now in BL (First/Calling) API, if the StatusCode is not Success then read the response result. Like this:

```
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var errorOutput = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    //Now send this errorOutput from this API to the client. Return an HTTPResult or another Content from here. Upto you!
}
return Ok(); //If response.statuscode is Success
```

Comment: that's helpful. passing Content is better as it supports custom error/message along with the Status Code.